# Searching in the source of a particular schema(PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, search, plsql, sql-like

In the source code if I want to find out something, say where a particular column is getting updated. I am using the below query to find where the column(BUCKET) of table(LEA_AGREEMENT_DTL)is getting updated.

```
select * from user_source where upper(text) like '%UPDATE%LEA_AGREEMENT_DTL%BUCKET%';
```

Now if the source in that paticular schem is written as below my query will tell me in which procedure the code is written :

```
  Update Lea_agreement_dtl Set Dpd = No_Days_OverDuE,  bucket=V_bucket
   where ProposalID = T_ProposalID;
```

But if the code is written as below my query will not give any result :

```
    Update Lea_agreement_dtl 
  Set Dpd = No_Days_OverDuE,  
  bucket=V_bucket
  where ProposalID = T_ProposalID;
```

My question is how should I modify my query to search in the source code of a particular schema/user so that I get successful result in both the cases. Basically I want to find all the procedure's/objects where this column is getting updated in that particular schema.

As per my analysis if the whole query is written in one line then i am able to search it otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: In `USER_SOURCE`, each line of the code is stored in a separate row. So you'll have to loop through each row.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 main approaches to this problem:

1. **Hack something together with string functions and regular expressions.**  This is the most common solution but is also full of holes.  Those holes may not matter depending on why you're searching for the code.  This is good enough for finding where to start coding but is probably not sufficient for proving to someone that the code is covered.
2. **Tokenize the input and loop through the tokens looking for a pattern.**  A lexer can take care of some problems that are not easily handled by single regular expressions, like comments and the alternative quoting syntax.  With a good understanding of Oracle syntax it's possible to build a highly-accurate solution.  It would still miss extremely broken code (for example, it's possible to create code with `UPDATE` as a variable), dynamic SQL, and recursive references through synonyms and views.
3. **Parse the input and walk an abstract syntax tree looking for a pattern.**  This would be a nice 100%-accurate solution.  Unfortunately there are no high-quality PL/SQL parsers available in PL/SQL.

The solution below uses an [open-source PL/SQL lexer](https://github.com/method5/plsql_lexer) I created to solve problems like this.

**Sample Procedure**

The string pattern, UPDATE-LEA_AGREEMENT_DTL-BUCKET, occurs three times below.  But only the first `UPDATE` on line 4 really satisfies the conditions.  (The third update may look weird in the Stackoverflow syntax highlighting, but in real PL/SQL that second quotation mark does not close the string.)

```
create or replace procedure search_test is
begin
  --Real match.
  Update Lea_agreement_dtl Set Dpd = No_Days_OverDuE,
   bucket=V_bucket
   where ProposalID = T_ProposalID;

  --Exclude - ignore comments.
  /*Update Lea_agreement_dtl Set Dpd = No_Days_OverDuE,  bucket=V_bucket
   where ProposalID = T_ProposalID;*/

  --Exclude - watch out for alternative quoting syntax. 
  Update Lea_agreement_dtl Set Dpd = q'[No_Days_OverDuE',  bucket=V_bucket ]'
   where ProposalID = T_ProposalID;
end;
/
```

**Anonymous Block to Find the Lines**

```
--Find lines that update LEA_AGREEMENT_DTL.BUCKET.
--Does not search dynamic SQL and does not recurse through view or synonyms.
declare
    v_tokens token_table;

    v_update_line_number number;
    v_has_update boolean := false;
    v_has_table boolean := false;
    v_has_column boolean := false;
begin
    --Get source and tokenize it.
    v_tokens := tokenizer.tokenize(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCEDURE', 'SEARCH_TEST'));

    --Loop through tokens and look for UPDATE/LEA_AGREEMENT_DTL/BUCKET between semicolons.
    for i in 1 .. v_tokens.count loop
        --Reset if a semicolon is found.
        if v_tokens(i).value = ';' then
            v_has_update := false;
            v_has_table := false;
            v_has_column := false;
        --Look for relevant tokens, in order.
        elsif upper(v_tokens(i).value) = 'UPDATE' then
            v_update_line_number := v_tokens(i).line_number;
            v_has_update := true;
        elsif v_has_update and upper(v_tokens(i).value) = 'LEA_AGREEMENT_DTL' then
            v_has_table := true;
        elsif v_has_table and upper(v_tokens(i).value) = 'BUCKET' then
            v_has_column := true;
        end if;

        --Success if all conditions are met.
        if v_has_update and v_has_table and v_has_column then
            --Subtract 1 because DBMS_METADATA put a blank line at the beginning.
            dbms_output.put_line('Found on line '||to_char(v_update_line_number-1));
            v_has_update := false;
            v_has_table := false;
            v_has_column := false;
        end if;

    end loop;
end;
/
```

**Results**

```
Found on line 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `view`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_UPDATE_USER_SOURCE AS
SELECT TYPE,
           NAME,
           line,
           LISTAGG(regexp_replace(text,'[[:space:]]',' '), ' ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY norder) text
      FROM (SELECT a.TYPE,
                   a.NAME,
                   a.line,
                   b.text,
                   b.line norder
              FROM (SELECT line,
                           TYPE,
                           NAME,
                           text
                      FROM user_source
                     WHERE regexp_like(text, '[[:space:]]update[[:space:]]', 'i')) a,
                   user_source b
             WHERE a.type = b.TYPE
               AND a.name = b.name
               AND b.line BETWEEN a.line AND (SELECT MIN(g.line)
                                                FROM user_source g
                                               WHERE regexp_like(g.TEXT, ';', 'i')
                                                 AND g.TYPE = a.TYPE
                                                 AND g.NAME = a.name
                                                 AND g.line >= a.line)
             ORDER BY b.TYPE,
                      b.NAME,
                      b.line) c
     GROUP BY TYPE,
              NAME,
              line
```

`LISTAGG` working on Oracle 11g or higher.
If you using previous version Oracle, you need this `view`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_UPDATE_USER_SOURCE AS
SELECT TYPE,
         NAME,
         line,
         XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, regexp_replace(text, '[[:space:]]', ' ') || ' ')).EXTRACT('//text()') text
FROM (SELECT a.TYPE,
                         a.NAME,
                         a.line,
                         b.text,
                         b.line norder
                FROM (SELECT line,
                                         TYPE,
                                         NAME,
                                         text
                                FROM user_source
                             WHERE regexp_like(text, '[[:space:]]update[[:space:]]', 'i')) a,
                         user_source b
             WHERE a.type = b.TYPE
                 AND a.name = b.name
                 AND b.line BETWEEN a.line AND (SELECT MIN(g.line)
                                                                                    FROM user_source g
                                                                                 WHERE regexp_like(g.TEXT, ';', 'i')
                                                                                     AND g.TYPE = a.TYPE
                                                                                     AND g.NAME = a.name
                                                                                     AND g.line >= a.line)
             ORDER BY b.TYPE,
                                b.NAME,
                                b.line)
       GROUP BY TYPE,
                NAME,
                line;
```

It returns the data set, which contains all the `update` is in line with a number, in which the `update` started.

`View` can be used with [regexp_like](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm):

```
select * from V_UPDATE_USER_SOURCE t where regexp_like(text,'clients.*STATE','i')
```

Description:

- **clients** - table.
- **STATE** - column for update.